# java elastic-search connection issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, elasticsearch

i have a java application which sends log to elastic search, while i was implementing that application i got an error like this.

`08:20:39.498 [main] INFO  c.e.E.ElasticsearchExampleApplication - Starting ElasticsearchExampleApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 1.8.0_362 on 1291d5986694 with PID 8 (/app/ElasticsearchExample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by root in /app)  08:20:39.501 [main] INFO  c.e.E.ElasticsearchExampleApplication - No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"  08:20:39,751 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[null] - Attempted to append to non started appender [null]. 08:20:39,751 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[null] - Attempted to append to non started appender [null]. 08:20:39,751 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[null] - Attempted to append to non started appender [null]. 08:20:39.762 [es-writer-1] WARN  es-error-logger - Failed to send events to Elasticsearch: Connection refused (Connection refused)  08:20:39,762 |-WARN in com.internetitem.logback.elasticsearch.util.ErrorReporter@37e20cce - Failed to send events to Elasticsearch: Connection refused (Connection refused) 08:20:40.013 [es-writer-1] WARN  es-error-logger - Failed to send events to Elasticsearch: Connection refused (Connection refused)  08:20:40,013 |-WARN in com.internetitem.logback.elasticsearch.util.ErrorReporter@37e20cce - Failed to send events to Elasticsearch: Connection refused (Connection refused) 08:20:40.013 [main] INFO  c.e.E.ElasticsearchExampleApplication - Started ElasticsearchExampleApplication in 0.899 seconds (JVM running for 1.393)  Strating 08:20:40.016 [main] INFO  c.e.E.ElasticsearchExampleApplication - exiting the application  08:20:40.264 [es-writer-1] WARN  es-error-logger - Failed to send events to Elasticsearch: Connection refused (Connection refused)  08:20:40,264 |-WARN in com.internetitem.logback.elasticsearch.util.ErrorReporter@37e20cce - Failed to send events to Elasticsearch: Connection refused (Connection refused) 08:20:40.515 [es-writer-1] WARN  es-error-logger - Failed to send events to Elasticsearch: Connection refused (Connection refused)  08:20:40,516 |-WARN in com.internetitem.logback.elasticsearch.util.ErrorReporter@37e20cce - Failed to send events to Elasticsearch: Connection refused (Connection refused) 08:20:40.767 [es-writer-1] WARN  es-error-logger - Failed to send events to Elasticsearch: Connection refused (Connection refused)  08:20:40,767 |-WARN in com.internetitem.logback.elasticsearch.util.ErrorReporter@37e20cce - Failed to send events to Elasticsearch: Connection refused (Connection refused)`

the elastic search kibana and the java application is running as dockerized.
here is the pom file

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.11</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ElasticsearchExample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ElasticsearchExample</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
            <dependency>
      <groupId>com.internetitem</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-elasticsearch-appender</artifactId>
       <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

here is the logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration debug="true" scan="true">

  <!-- when the profile is not local, below appender will be applied -->
   <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
    <appender name="ELASTIC" class="com.internetitem.logback.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAppender">
        <url>localhost:9200/_bulk</url>
        <index>demo-%date{yyyy-MM-dd}</index>
        <type>tester</type>
        <loggerName>es-logger</loggerName> <!-- optional -->
        <errorLoggerName>es-error-logger</errorLoggerName> <!-- optional -->
        <connectTimeout>30000</connectTimeout> <!-- optional (in ms, default 30000) -->
        <errorsToStderr>false</errorsToStderr> <!-- optional (default false) -->
        <includeCallerData>false</includeCallerData> <!-- optional (default false) -->
        <logsToStderr>false</logsToStderr> <!-- optional (default false) -->
        <maxQueueSize>104857600</maxQueueSize> <!-- optional (default 104857600) -->
        <maxRetries>3</maxRetries> <!-- optional (default 3) -->
        <readTimeout>30000</readTimeout> <!-- optional (in ms, default 30000) -->
        <sleepTime>250</sleepTime> <!-- optional (in ms, default 250) -->
        <rawJsonMessage>false</rawJsonMessage> <!-- optional (default false) -->
        <includeMdc>false</includeMdc> <!-- optional (default false) -->
        <maxMessageSize>100</maxMessageSize> <!-- optional (default -1 -->
        <authentication class="com.internetitem.logback.elasticsearch.config.BasicAuthentication" /> <!-- optional -->
        <properties>
            <property>
                <name>host</name>
                <value>${HOSTNAME}</value>
                <allowEmpty>false</allowEmpty>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>severity</name>
                <value>%level</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>thread</name>
                <value>%thread</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>stacktrace</name>
                <value>%ex</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>logger</name>
                <value>%logger</value>
            </property>
        </properties>
        <headers>
            <header>
                <name>Content-Type</name>
                <value>application/json</value>
            </header>
        </headers>
    </appender>
    <!-- We don't want to see a never ending cascade of connection failed ERRORS -->
    <!-- <logger name="my-error-logger" level="OFF" /> -->
    <logger name="es-logger" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender name="ES_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <encoder>
                <pattern>%msg</pattern> <!-- This pattern is important, otherwise it won't be the raw Elasticsearch format anymore -->
            </encoder>
        </appender>
    </logger>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="ELASTIC" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

here is the docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.12.1
    #image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.16
    #image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.0
    container_name: my-elasticsearch
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    networks:
      core:

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.12.1
    #image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:5.6.16
    #image: yuzu/docker-kibana:v5.0
    container_name: my-kibana
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      core:

  my-java-app:
    image: my-java-app:latest
    container_name: my-java-app
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./logs:/app/logs
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx512m -Dspring.profiles.active=prod
    networks:
      core:

networks:
  core:
```

can anyone please help me

Comment: What do you get when pinging the ES server at `curl -XGET http://localhost:9200` ? Can you also try `http://host.docker.internal:9200` ?

Comment: {
  "name" : "06e214ebbc85",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "iRJVvBFoTSOP2d2u4cfoWw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.12.1",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "3186837139b9c6b6d23c3200870651f10d3343b7",
    "build_date" : "2021-04-20T20:56:39.040728659Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.8.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}

Comment: curl -XGET http://host.docker.internal:9200
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: host.docker.internal

Comment: any lead to solve

Comment: What happens is that the `my-java-app` container tries to send data to the `elasticsearch` container using `localhost` (i.e. the same container). Can you try this url instead `<url>elasticsearch:9200/_bulk</url>` ?

Comment: connection refused. but curl http://elasticsearch:9200/ is working fine inside that container to the elastic container

Comment: Aside from that, it's considered a bad practice to ship logs directly from your app to ES because you're adding a direct dependency between your app and the availability of ES. What happens if the ES container is down for some reason? You should prefer logging to a file and use Filebeat to tail that file and send it up ES.

Comment: what change we need to do in the docker-compose , pom.xml ,logback.xml

Comment: how to do those changes ? any way to sent directly even if it is a bad practice

Comment: Just for completeness sake, can you add the scheme as well, i.e. `<url>http://elasticsearch:9200/_bulk</url>`

Comment: it is not working 14:38:22.417 [es-writer-6] WARN  es-error-logger - Failed to send events to Elasticsearch: Connection refused (Connection refused) 
14:38:22,417 |-WARN in com.internetitem.logback.elasticsearch.util.ErrorReporter@4613ea7b - Failed to send events to Elasticsearch: Connection refused (Connection refused)